# Try block fall-through?

Tags: python

Maybe this is a basic question by I don't see why the code below executes the `except` block in all cases:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os

try:
    if sys.argv[1] == '-d':
        for i in range(1,len(sys.argv[:])):
            arg = sys.argv[i]
            print(i,arg)
    sys.exit(0)
except:
    print ("Syntax: python mergeTXT2XL.py working-dir output-name txt-file1 txt-file2 ...")
    sys.exit(-1)
```

When I run this with args:

```
python mergeTxt2XL.py -d 1 2 3 4
```

I get this:

```
1 -d
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4

Syntax: python mergeTXT2XL.py working-dir output-name txt-file1 txt-file2 ...
```

The syntax line should NOT be printing.  It looks like pass-through/fall-through.

Comment: you should sometimes print the exception like this `except Exception as e:` next line `print(e)` because then you will know the cause of executing except block

Answer (score 4):

[`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) works internally by raising a [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) exception. Your `except` block catches it. This is why you should always do `except Exception` when you want an unspecific catch-all, since in the [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) `Exception` does *not* include `SystemException` among a few others you typically don't want to catch.

Comment: actually exception printed out that `list index is out of range`

Comment: That might be an additional problem, but OP will always encounter the `sys.exit` problem no matter what…

Comment: @Matiiss I don't see how you'd get an `IndexError` here. OP is using a loop to iterate over `sys.argv` (albeit not idiomatically). The only way to get it is to execute the code with no arguments at all (which is not OP's case)

Comment: well thats what `except Exception as e:` printed out

Comment: @Matiiss Because you executed the script with no arguments at all, so `sys.argv[1]` did not exist. That is not what OP is doing.